# Unable to call an interceptor before MultipartResolver in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my spring-3 application I have an AuthenticationInterceptor (which is basically an interceptor) that checks for the privileges for a user. I am using a Spring's `MultipartResolver` to try an upload a file to the server.
The problem that I now face is that I wish to perform different actions based on user privileges, in case of a `MaxUploadSizeExceededException`.
However I see that this exception is occurring at the DispatcherServlet level and is caught by `HandlerExceptionResolver`
I want to be able to call my AuthenticationInterceptor before any of this happens?
Is there a straightforward way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the exception occurs BEFORE the request is dispatched to a controller and because of that, your interceptor also never fires.  I guess you have that part figured out already.

Want to get around that...

For starters, I would move the authentication mechanism out IN FRONT of the servlet by using servlet filters.  This being said, it makes little or no sense to roll your own solution in that space when a great product like Spring Security can do that for you.

Once you transition to Spring Security (or similar), the user's SecurityContext (roles, permissions, etc.) will have been resolved by the time the exception occurs and is caught.

Now, if I'm reading your question correctly, it seems you might like to respond to the exception differently based on the user's roles, permissions, etc.  That should be possible at this point.  You'd implement a custom HandlerExceptionResolver that inspects the SecurityContext to see if the user has a certain role or permission and then respond accordingly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: But I already have the authentication mechanism in place and I wouldn't want to change that now. Plus I am curious about the order in which these components are called. When you say that 
**exception occurs BEFORE the request is dispatched to a controller and because of that, your interceptor also never fires** 
I am curious as to why that is the case.

Comment: There is a generic pattern called the "filter pattern" that involves preprocessing of requests.  Servlet filters are an implementation of that pattern.  Spring MVC's interceptors are another implementation of the same pattern.  The difference is WHERE they intercept/preprocess the requests.  A servlet filter preprocesses requests BEFORE the requests ever hit the servlet (in this case, Spring MVC's DispatcherServlet).  The Interceptors, however, perform preprocessing on a request before the DispatcherServlet dispatches the request to one of your controllers.

Comment: What you need, in order to meet your requirements, is to intercept/preprocess requests BEFORE the request hits the DispatcherServlet. That means using a servlet filter, and as I indicated, there is a terrific security implementation already available that is based on this- Spring Security.  If you want to keep going with your AuthInterceptor, more power to you, but what you're looking to achieve isn't achievable via that approach. In general, I think also that you're better off using a proven solution that a million before you have already put to the test rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways to handle doing something in-stream before the Handler code gets called:

1. Implement the `HandlerInterceptor` interface, and code the code you want to run in the `preHandle` method
2. Create an Aspect using `@Aspect` and configure a pointcut to run `@Before` the method call

In either case, you could check the logged-in user's Roles using `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()` and then decide what to do based on Role membership.

Comment: This basis on this solution is also I believe that I use the SrpingSecurity module of Spring?

Comment: No - the HandlerInterceptor is available regardless of whether you use Spring Security or not